# Анимация при наведении в липком меню

Tags: html, jquery, css

Решил сделать анимацию при наведении в липком меню.
При *scroll'е*, когда меню в скрытом состоянии, при наведении на иконку появляется блок *"Забронировать"*, а когда убираешь мышь, блок *"Забронировать"* прячется.

Для этого я написал простенький скрипт, но он себя очень странно ведет.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > $('header .top_header').outerHeight()) {
    if ($(' .right_nav .reservations div:last-child').hide(300)) {
      $(' .right_nav .reservations div:first-child').mouseenter(function() {
        $(' .right_nav .reservations div:last-child').show(200);
      }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(' .right_nav .reservations div:last-child').hide(300);
      })
    }

  } else {
    $(' .right_nav .reservations div:last-child').show(200);
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
}

header .top_header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: DINPro-Light, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.375em;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  margin: 0;
}

header .top_header .left_nav {
  float: left;
}

header .top_header .left_nav .menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: -6px;
  max-width: 60px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

header .top_header .left_nav .menu img {
  padding: 0 8px;
  width: 55px;
}

header .top_header .left_nav .tel {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 16px;
}

header .top_header .right_nav {
  float: right;
}

header .top_header .right_nav .reservations {
  background-color: #cba673;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: -6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .top_header .right_nav .reservations div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 60px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

header .top_header .right_nav .reservations div:last-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-right: 18px;
}

header .top_header .right_nav .language {
  margin-left: -6px;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="top_header">
    <div class="left_nav">
      <div class="menu">
        |||
      </div>
      <div class="tel">
        +38 097 060 05 57
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_nav">
      <div class="reservations">
        <div>[|||]</div>
        <div>Забронировать</div>
      </div>
      <div class="language">
        Eng
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Почему это так происходит и как это можно решить?

[Пример на Codepen](http://codepen.io/jSas/pen/GrvoJE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все дело в том, что вы повесили `mouseenter` не на весь желтый блок (`.reservations`) а только на иконку (`.reservations div:first-child`). Что происходит в результате:

1. Как только вы наводите мышь на иконку - она уезжает из под мыши.
2. Как только она уехала из под мыши срабатывает `mouseleave` и иконка едет обратно.
3. Как только иконка доехала до мыши снова срабатывает `mouseenter` и все повторяется с пункта 1.

Что надо сделать - повесить все события на весь желтый блок (`.reservations`)

```
  $(' .right_nav .reservations').hover(function() {
    //mouseenter
    $(' .right_nav .reservations div:last-child').show(200);
  },function() {
    //mouseleave
    $(' .right_nav .reservations div:last-child').hide(300);
  })
```

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > $('header .top_header').outerHeight()) {
    if ($(' .right_nav .reservations div:last-child').hide(300)) {
      $(' .right_nav .reservations').hover(function() {
        $(' .right_nav .reservations div:last-child').show(200);
      },function() {
        $(' .right_nav .reservations div:last-child').hide(300);
      })
    }

  } else {
    $(' .right_nav .reservations div:last-child').show(200);
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
}

header .top_header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: DINPro-Light, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.375em;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  margin: 0;
}

header .top_header .left_nav {
  float: left;
}

header .top_header .left_nav .menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: -6px;
  max-width: 60px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

header .top_header .left_nav .menu img {
  padding: 0 8px;
  width: 55px;
}

header .top_header .left_nav .tel {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 16px;
}

header .top_header .right_nav {
  float: right;
}

header .top_header .right_nav .reservations {
  background-color: #cba673;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-right: -6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .top_header .right_nav .reservations div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 60px !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

header .top_header .right_nav .reservations div:last-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-right: 18px;
}

header .top_header .right_nav .language {
  margin-left: -6px;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 0 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="top_header">
    <div class="left_nav">
      <div class="menu">
        |||
      </div>
   
    </div>
    <div class="right_nav">
      <div class="reservations">
        <div>[|||]</div>
        <div>Забронировать</div>
      </div>
      <div class="language">
        Eng
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique deserunt culpa earum, ducimus ab! Doloribus in similique, harum iusto suscipit vero, eos odio laudantium illo, ipsam saepe eius quod beatae.</p>
  </div>
</header>
```